# Не работает метод header() php!

Tags: php, header

```
<? if($_COOKIE['user'] == ''): ?>
    <div id="regDiv"></div>
    <? else: ?>
    <? include("B:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\index.php") ?>
    <? header("Content-type: text/html; charset: utf=8;"); ?>
    <? endif; ?>
```

Пробовал писать в header("index.php"), не получается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать!

Comment: вы не можете устанавливать заголовки ответа сервера (header) после того, как вывели что-то на страницу. То есть любой вывод из буфера (это ваши `echo` или просто html-код) должен начинаться после установки заголовков

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, все равно не понимаю, где в моем коде ошибка. Перед header() я ничего не выводил.

Comment: В том коде, который Вы привели, 2-я строчка `<div id="regDiv"></div>` - это вывод. 4-я строчка, где инклюд, в файле тоже наверняка что-то выводится. После этих выводов уже нельзя устанавливать `header('...')`

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов аа понятно. А есть идеи, как можно решить по-другому?

Comment: честно говоря, не понимаю, в чем задача, что решить-то. Зачем вам вообще header() в этом примере? Content-type можно установить, просто добавив мета-тег в html код.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов на этой странице есть форма, я ее скрыл. После ее проверки нужно переходить на другую страницу

Comment: в форме напишите `<form action="путь/на/вашу/другую/страницу">...</form>`, и уже там проверяйте, на этой станице. Если ок, показываете страницу, если нет - показываете ошибку или как раз с помощью `header('Location: ...` перенаправляете обратно на форму логина. Обычно делается так.

Comment: @Максим Степанов можно в форме просто добавить какой нибудь GET и после обработки формы сделать перенаправление на оригинальный адрес без GET